How to capture Errors from Firefox browser console using Playwright Python
I want to capture console logs from Firefox web browser using Playwright Python and attach the same to Allure Report.
I am able to fetch Warnings, Logs, Info and Debug messages from browser console, but not able to fetch full message of ** Errors**
page.on("console", print_args)

def print_args(msg):
    if msg.type == "error":
        page.on("console", print(f"ERROR: {msg.page}", file=sys.stderr))
    elif msg.type == "warn":
        page.on("console", print(f"WARNING: {msg.text}", file=sys.stderr))
    elif msg.type == "log":
        page.on("console", print(f"LOG: {msg.text}", file=sys.stderr))
    elif msg.type == "debug":
        page.on("console", print(f"DEBUG: {msg.text}", file=sys.stderr))
    elif msg.type == "info":
        page.on("console", print(f"INFO: {msg.text}", file=sys.stderr))
    else:
        print(f"Unrecognized msg type: {msg.type}", file=sys.stderr)

This is the error displays in console 
But what I am able to fetch using the code above is just ERROR: Error (as given below):
Actual
Note:
The same code works for MS Edge and Google Chrome browsers, but not working for Firefox browser.
I really appreciate if someone can explain how to capture full error message from Firefox browser console.
python version: 3.12.3
